# Dropdownlist becomes empty when selection changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I am new to c# and asp.net. I have a `GridView` with certain records. When any record is chosen it is displayed in the `DetailsView`. My details view has 3 `DropDownLists`. In the edit mode of my details view, when I changed my selection in the drop down list and update it, the particular field takes null values. I have used `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and I am sure its getting triggered but the values is null. Here is my code.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)this.form1.FindControl("DropDownList1");
    hi.Visible = true;
    if (ddl != null)
    {
        ddl.Text = ddl.SelectedItem.Value;
        ddl.DataBind();
    }     
}
```

I have also tried using the `SelectedValue` property to update but that didnt work too.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" DataTextField="strCollegeLongName"
    DataValueField="strCollegeLongName" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" autoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="false" 
    SelectedValue='<%#Bind="College">%'>
</asp:DropDownList>

UpdateCommand="UPDATE [RegistrationFormInfo] SET [FirstName]=@FirstName,
    [LastName]=@LastName,[EmailAddress]=@EmailAddress,[GradDate]=@GradDate,
    [WorkAuth]=@WorkAuth,[Address]=@Address,[Phone]=@Phone,[UFID]=@UFID,
    [GatorAcct]=@GatorAcct,[College]=@College,[Major]=@Major,[UserType]=@UserType,
    [AdminUser]=@AdminUser,[blnActive]=@blnActive,[EntryTS]=@EntryTS WHERE [Guid]=@Guid "
```

So, here it throws an error saying `@College` doest not exist, but my table has `College` column.

I am stuck and any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the @College error is probably about the named parameter not being provided, not about the column being missing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)this.form1.FindControl("DropDownList1");`, try this:

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ddl.DataBind();` will reset the `SelectedIndex`.  To avoid circular logic in your code it's a bad idea to call `DataBind()` in a ddl's `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler.